# Utilizing bash to multiply an interger by a float with an if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, floating-point, int, multiplication

Utilizing bash to multiply an interger by a float with an if statement, I will further expand on this with two other cases outside 0.90, just trying to learn the basics.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "give me an integer: [ENTER]: "
read that_integer

if -n [ $that_integer <= 5000 ]; then
awk print $that_integer*0.90 
done
```

Ultimately, this is the code I came up with.

Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "give me an integer: [ENTER]: "
read that_integer

if [ $that_integer -le 5000 ]; then
awk -v x=$that_integer 'BEGIN { print x*0.90 }' < /dev/null

elif [ $that_integer -gt 5000 -a $that_integer -le 50000 ]; then
awk -v x=$that_integer 'BEGIN { print x*0.70 }' < /dev/null

else
awk -v x=$that_integer 'BEGIN { print x*0.40 }' < /dev/null
fi 
done
```

Comment: +1 for good early question.  Of course  you could do all of this in 1 line of awk, (with only 1 process creation in all cases), i.e. `awk -v i=$that_int 'BEGIN{if (i<5000) print i*.9 else if (i>5000 && i <=50000) print i*.7 else print i*.4}'` Good luck and keep poinsting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`bc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/bc.html) utility to do floating point arithmetic in the shell.

```
echo "give me an integer: [ENTER]: "
read that_integer

if [ $that_integer -le 5000 ]; then
    echo "$that_integer*0.90"|bc
elif [ $that_integer -gt 5000 -a $that_integer -le 50000 ]; then
    echo "$that_integer*0.70"|bc
else
    echo "$that_integer*0.40"|bc
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-n` does nothing; remove it.

For integer comparisons, use `-le`:

```
if [ $that_integer -le 5000 ]; then
```

The correct syntax for the `awk` call is

```
awk -v x=$that_integer 'BEGIN { print x*0.90 }' < /dev/null
```

`if` statements are terminated with `fi`, not `done`.

Comment: You don't need `< /dev/null` in `awk`

Comment: Right but with `BEGIN` it won't need it. `awk -v x=4 'BEGIN{print 5*x}'` also works.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that if the only rule is a `BEGIN` rule, it would ignore standard input.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, `bash` can't handle floats, but you can re-cast this to use integer maths:

```
x=$((5000*90/100))

echo $x
4500
```

So, just for kicks:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "give me an integer: [ENTER]: "
read that_integer

multiplier=40
[ $that_integer -le 5000 ] && multiplier=90
[ $that_integer -gt 5000 -a $that_integer -le 50000 ] && multiplier=70
echo $(($that_integer*$multiplier/100))
```